# Tire Size Calculator as a Stack Snippet?

Tags: feature-request

We get tire size questions [every](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/9768/675) [now](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/19825/675) [and](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/17036/675) [again](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/16401/675).

It would be cool if we could create a runnable [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269754/133939) that:

- takes in a tire size as input and generates a to-scale diagram of the wheel with width, height, inner diameter dimensions printed
- takes two tire sizes as input and advises about changes in dimensions (go/no-go)

At the moment we usually link to an external site that performs the calculations, which is bad for a couple of reasons:

- link permanence not guaranteed
- I always forget which site I used in my last answer to a "tire-size" question

---

### Questions

1. Does the Mech.SE community agree there is value in undertaking this activity?
2. Is it possible to run Stack Snippets on a Beta site like this? If not, what will it take to enable such? In the worst-case scenario I guess we could always link to the [Snippets Sandbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269754/133939)
3. Do Stack Snippets allow users to input values? I imagine it should be readily available through a message box at the very least
4. Do we have expertise to implement these simple calculations? I have zero experience with JS, but can flesh out the details for the calculations if there is sufficient interest.

Comment: It's a great idea, but in actuality, the numbers on the sidewall can be as much as a half inch off from a physical measurement. Such a tool would be fun to see as a *possibility* for upsizing your wheels or something, but it will always come down to the test fit. Plenty of times I've done the math and it should work, but it doesn't work on the test fit. Such instances will rub, usually on front left while turning hard left.

Comment: But also, the formula is really not that complicated. `(Section width * (.01 * ratio)) + (25.4 * wheel diameter)`. So a 235/65R17 would be `(235 * (.01 * 65)) + (25.4 * 17) = 584.5 mm`. Convert that back to inches by dividing by 25.4, which is a pinch over 23 inches in this case. Now, if you are in the imperially sized tires, like a 35x12.50R16, the first number is your answer already. It's 35 inches high.

Comment: Now, if you are in the imperial sized tires, like a 35x12.50R16, the first number is your answer already. It's 35 inches high. If you need to convert to the metric, just multiply the middle number (12.50 in this case) by 25.4 to get the section width in mm. That's 317, so you're looking for something that starts with 315, but could very likely fit a 305 or even 295, but a 325 would be pushing it (if you can find it).